# Java annotation example in official docs

Tags: java, interface, annotations

While reading the Oracle documentation on annotations (quite new to this concept), I came across the following snippet in the beginning (link at the bottom). I am not clear on what the example is illustrating. Is the public @interface definition an enhanced version of a normal interface definition? id(), engineer() etc are methods that return default values if not specified in the interface implementation? But then the instantiation is confusing, is it providing an implementation of an interface where id() returns 2868724 etc? Also not clear what the function travelThroughTime() is for. Any clarifications appreciated:

```
/**
* Describes the Request-For-Enhancement(RFE) that led
* to the presence of the annotated API element.
*/
 public @interface RequestForEnhancement {
   int    id();
   String synopsis();
   String engineer() default "[unassigned]"; 
   String date();    default "[unimplemented]"; 
 }

 @RequestForEnhancement(
   id       = 2868724,
   synopsis = "Enable time-travel",
   engineer = "Mr. Peabody",
   date     = "4/1/3007"
 )
 public static void travelThroughTime(Date destination) { ... }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break down your questions:

**Is `@interface` just an enhancement of `interface`**?:
No, `@interface` is declaring something quite different from a standard `interface`- you are essentially declaring an annotation type. Making this declaration enables the declared thing to be used as an annotation in other code. So the declaration:

```
 public @interface RequestForEnhancement
```

enables the annotation `@RequestForEnhancement` to be used in later code.
An annotation describes metadata for a method or a class. The `@RequestForEnhancement` annotation, for example, might be placed in front of a method in another class to indicate that some developer wants that method to be changed in some way.

Declaring an `interface`, by contrast, is declaring the signature of a group of functions. Classes which later implement an interface must then provide implementations of those functions.

**What are the "methods" (`synopsis()`, `engineer()`, etc.) in the annotation body for?** These are not really methods like you would be used to seeing in a class or interface definition. Instead, these represent fields that the annotation you've just declared has. A `@RequestForEnhancement` annotation on a method should indicate what the requested change to the method is, and possibly who is expected to implement the enhancement to the method. Thus the fields `synopsis` and `engineer` are fields that can be included in the annotation.

**What does this section mean?:**

```
@RequestForEnhancement(
  id       = 2868724,
  synopsis = "Enable time-travel",
  engineer = "Mr. Peabody",
  date     = "4/1/3007"
)
public static void travelThroughTime(Date destination) { ... }
```

This is an example of using the annotation that we've declared in the block starting with `@RequestForEnhancement`. Usages like this will likely occur all over your codebase, in many different classes, once the annotation has been defined. In this particular example, there is a method `travelThroughTime(Date destination)` in some class which apparently doesn't work very well. Some developer coming across the method thought it should be improved by making it do what it appears to claim to do (travel through time). That developer decided to reflect his request by putting an `@RequestForEnhancement` annotation on the method with some information about when the request was made, who was expected to  make the enhancement, etc.

**Sure, but how do you *use* the contents of an annotation for anything useful? (A question I'll ask for you :-) )**

So let's say I want to write a tool which looks through all of my code for methods annotated with `@RequestForEnhancement` and send an e-mail to the engineers listed in the request, along with information about the annotation and the request for enhancement. How would I get started?

The basic mechanism to find out what methods have an annotation and the way to get values from the annotation is through Java *reflection*. A tutorial which includes an example of annotations and reflection is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html#annotations_tutorial) (it's actually a good tutorial on annotations in general).

**So sure, you can use reflection to get info out of these annotations, but when would you run a tool to use the info from the annotations? (another one I'll ask for you)** Java provides the ability for you to define annotation processors which use annotation information when your code is compiled. Here's [what looks like a reasonable tutorial](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101/). You can also use the information in your annotations at runtime. If you've ever used JavaFX, for example, you may have noticed that annotations can affect runtime behavior (adding @FXML to a field helps JavaFX fill that field with a value defined in your fxml).

Comment: Thanks thats a little more clear. So the travelThroughTime() function in the above example is going to use the metadata declared through the @RequestForEnhancement annotation?

Comment: No, the `travelThroughTime` method will not use the contents of the annotation. The information contained in the annotation will likely be used for maitenance of the codebase. The owners of a codebase using the annotation `@RequestForEnhancement` might have an automated tool, for example, to search through the code for all such requests and send an e-mail to the engineer listed in the annotation, along with the other content of the request. **The annotation is *about* the method, it is not a part of the method.**

Comment: @user3079275 http://ideone.com/vk6pah is a small example that includes using the methods defined in an annotation (line 33)